# Renaming or deleting Lead Status field?

Tags: fields, standard-objects

Is there any possibility to rename, delete or even hide Lead Status field?

Comment: Did you not find it from: `Setup` >> `Customize` >> `Leads` >> `Fields` >> `Lead Status`. Documentation: [Setup and display of converted Lead status values](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003713&type=1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do all these things on Lead Status.

[image]

Here is a standard UI where we get all these option to add/remove, rename , set as default a picklist value.